# What is the difference between an active, relay and passive stake pool node?

Tags: stake-pool

I have seen three types of stake pool nodes mentioned.

1. Active
2. Relay
3. Passive

How do they differ in purpose and function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The term active node is often used to describe a node with the purpose of minting new blocks.
2. The term relay node is used to describe a node that is run by the stake pool operator to relay the newly minted blocks from their block producer (active node) to the rest of the Cardano network. See [What are relay nodes?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-are-relay-nodes)
3. A passive node is a node within the Cardano network that is receiving blocks and transactions from their peers (and in the future, will share these with its peers). A good example of an passive node is the Daedalus full node wallet.

Note that all type of nodes connected to the Cardano network can be used to submit a valid transaction to the network.